# How to cancel the DPD UK label from API (Web API C#)

Tags: c#, shipping-method

```
var finalBookingUrl = "https://api.dpd.co.uk/shipping/shipment/{ShipmentId}?action=Void"    
dynamic result = await $"{finalBookingUrl}"
                                   .AllowAnyHttpStatus()
                                   .WithHeaders(new { GEOClient = loginId, GEOSession = geoSession, Accept = "application/json" })
                                   .PutJsonAsync(shipmentVoid);
```

Comment: I am requesting to cancel the shipment label from C# web API, i am providing all the details in the header but server response with 404, how ever other API am able to get the the possitive responce, Please help.

Comment: I don't know, but you appear to be missing a `$` for the interpolated URL on the first line. Have you used Fiddler or other transparent proxy to compare the working and non-working requests?

Comment: var finalBookingUrl = "https://api.dpd.co.uk/shipping/shipment/1040277237?action=Void" this is the final output of line number one

Comment: I tried in postman with same URL with all header details and server respond like "Cannot PUT /esgServer/shipping/shipment/1040277237?action=Void"

Comment: Please suggest me, is it possble to void the shipment label from the c# Web api or not. However I can void the same shipment label from the original portal (https://www.dpd.co.uk/) by login with credential, Please help, it killing my time from many days, thanks.